# Deleted photos reappear after reboot, new photos dissapear

Tags: sd-card, photos, sony-xperia, 8.0-oreo, delete

I try to delete all the pictures I have on my SD card. I just select all of them and click the trash icon. When I finish, I see an empty folder, as expected. I make a new photo. And then I reboot my mobile phone. When I enter the album I see all the photos I deleted, and the photo I created after the deletion is missing.

Why is this happening?

**Edit no 1:**

Phone: Sony Xperia XA1

Android 8.0.0

I deleted everything from the [Album app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.album&hl=en_US)

**Edit no 2:**

I unchecked cloud backup, but still have the same problem. I can erase all photos I have, but after restart they still return in seconds.

Where are they stored? Can I erase them manually?

**Edit no 3:**

Here's what I tried so far. Provided by someone from the [talk.sonymobile.com](https://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-XA1/Cloud-restore-makes-it-impossible-to-delete-files-from-sd-card/m-p/1370336#M6644) forum:

settings > apps & notifications > all apps > album > storage > clear data > restart the phone > check again.

Did not work.

Comment: Would be handy to include a few more technical details. Which phone, version of Android and clarify where you're deleting the photos (are we to assume it is Google Photos or some file manager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appears the SD card stopped recording new data. Here's how I get to this point:

1. I ejected the microSD card from the phone.
2. Using a MicroSD to USB I inserted it to my computer.
3. I tried to delete the data, the adapter, inserted it again - noticed nothing has changed.
4. I tried to format the MicroSD, ejected the adapter, inserted it again - noticed nothing has changed.

I bought a new SD card, copied the backup (applications and stuff) to the new one. Photos work as they should.